# Java Script to get localhost+htdocs folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, localhost, hostname

I have following url to be build,

```
http://localhost/myweb/cart/index.php
```

I want to get the `http://localhost/myweb/` bit build dynamically.

To do that on my live web site which is http://www.myweb.com/cart/index.php I can use the following JavaScript code,

```
var http = location.protocol;
var slashes = http.concat("//");
var host = slashes.concat(window.location.hostname);
```

But how do I get my development environment to work since it has `http://localhost/myweb/`? If I run the above code it will give me `http://localhost/` only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: since I have this in lot of places in my js files, but if I change them to have hard coded "myweb/" bit, I have to revert it back to put it in to the live and before commit the code in to SVN, and vice-versa

Comment: Your JS seems like the problem here. Why don't you use relative paths?

Comment: Didn't quite get you there...

Comment: Why is `myweb/` being hardcoded a problem?

Comment: coz in my local, my woking folder in htdocs/myweb/

Comment: But why is that a problem? What does it break?

Comment: If I uploads the file to the live site, i'll brake the live site

Comment: Well, what changes between the two sites?

Comment: so the live site doesn't have the myweb/ bit,  when it comes to the live site the whole localhost/myweb/ bit will be the domain name itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.pathname` is the thing you search for.

I would suggest you to read the MDN description of [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location). Like everything else in MDN, this is also really straightforward and informative.

If you know that the URL has an unnecessary index.html part at the end you can:

```
var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
path.pop();
path.join('/');
```

or you can slice it (since it is generally faster):

```
path.slice(0,path.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
```

---

**EDIT**:

Seeing your new question I can say that what you want can't be done consistently and safely by only the current URL.

You need the `http://localhost/myweb/` part, which is the URL root of your application. In javascript you are able to get the protocol and domain of the url. On your live site these 2 match, but if your application resides in a subfolder (like the `myweb` folder at your localhost), this will fail.

What you need is to somehow identify the application URL (the URL root of your application).

The problem is that by only examining the URL, javascript cannot tell where your application resides.

Let's say you deploy your site to: `http://localhost/myweb/site1/`

You will have the following URL: `http://localhost/myweb/site1/cart/index.php`

Javascript can split your URL by the slashes (`/`) but it has no way of nowing how many subfolders it should select. For example from the URL above your application root can be any of the following: `http://localhost/`, `http://localhost/myweb/`, `http://localhost/myweb/site1/`, `http://localhost/myweb/site1/cart/`.

By an other approach (which I suggested first) you can drop the end of the URL (in your case the `cart/index.php` part). This will only work if your URL structure IS very rigid, so all the pages this script is executed on reside in one subfolder.

So it will break on the following URL: `http://localhost/myweb/site1/gallery/old/index.php` or similar.

Your **best bet** would be to make this a "config variable" in a separate file which you edit on every location it is deployed to.

Either as a PHP variable (`$appRoot = "http://localhost/myweb/"`) which you generate the javascript with.

Or more simply a javascript variable (`var appRoot = 'http://localhost/myweb/'`). Make a separate js file, call it something like `config.js`, add the above line to it and reference it before your other javascripts.

Comment: window.location.pathname not gonna work though, I have edited my question to be more clear. Thanx anyway

Comment: Solution I'm looking at should be work in both live and dev environments, unfortunately this would only work in my local dev. coz if I have this on live it will brake the URL.

Comment: Your question changed drastically from the last time I saw it. Check out my updated answer!